# Declare long string for using few times in query statement ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to build a query in oracle and for some materials and I want to declare these materials once and I want to use this variable in the query. The variable will be a string of strings.

It is my query but is wrong. How I can write correct query :

```
enter code herev_material varchar2(18000) := '2421032060SST','2421040080SST','2421050080SST';
    
    SELECT MARA.MATERIAL,MARA.NAZWA_MATERIALU,MARA.JM,MARA.MAABC
    FROM OLAP_DANE.MV_SAP_MARA MARA
    Left outer join
    (select something
    from a
    where material in v_material)c
    on c.material in mara.material
    WHERE MARA.MATERIAL = v_material
    ;
```

Comment: On which Oracle client?

Comment: @JamesJithin does it matter if code is wrong?

Comment: @JamesJithin 11 OR 12 - ofc code is wrong is  pseudo code

Comment: @Seyran, the declaration of the variables are different for different clients. For SQL Plus it might be "var myvar varchar2(20); exec :myvar := 'VAR_NAME'". For another client DBeaver, it is "@set var_id=323"

Comment: @JamesJithin SQLPlus and DBeaver are not Oracle Clients. As a usual "oracle client" means version of Oracle Instant Client, as set lib and tools for working with Oracle DB. and SQLPlus is a one of the tools in OIC. And there is no matter what you use, in PL/SQL you can't declare `x varchar2(20) := 'abc','asb','asb';`

Answer (score 0):

Not only query wrong, declaration of string is also wrong. You can not declare string such way. 
1. For simple solution, if we can suppose  that values of materials are unique from comma to comma, you can declare string like

```
v_material varchar2(18000) := ',2421032060SST,2421040080SST,2421050080SST,';
```

and when use in query

```
... and instr(','|| MARA.Materials ||',', v_material) > 0
```

2. Or way two, and it's more right in my point of view.
declare schema level table type of string

```
create or replace type TStrings as table of varchar2(150);
```

declare

```
v_materials TStrings := TStrings('2421032060SST','2421040080SST','2421050080SST');
```

and then use in query like

```
...  select column_value from table(v_material) ...
```

something like this.